# Define a dcg for palindromes over the alphabet {a,b} of 2 symbols a and b such that the number of a's is one less than the number of b's

Tags: prolog, palindrome, dcg

I am trying to define a palindrome where the number of a's is one less than the number of b's.
I cant seem to figure out how to write it properly

```
   please-->palindromes.
   palindromes-->[].
   palindromes-->[a].
   palindromes-->[b].
   palindromes--> [b],palindromes,[b].
```

Comment: I think you can try harder than that.

Comment: your second and third base cases don't follow your rules.  They are not palindromes where the number of `a`'s is one less than the number of `b`'s

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: where the surplus 'b' could stay ? In a palindrome, there is only one such place. Then change the symmetric definition, that in BNF (you already know as translate to DCG) would read

```
S :: P
P :: a P a | b P b | {epsilon}
```

Comment: The surplus b could stay in the middle but a b a b is a valid palindrome

Comment: Yes, in the middle. But abab is not a palindrome, should be abba.

Comment: of course, to get equal count of a and b, these must be in pairs, `P :: ab P ba | ...`

Comment: The number of b's has to be 1 greater than the number of a's.

Comment: "there is only one such place" - false. You seem to be implying the center letter must be `b`, but `bab` also satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you just need a way to deal with the difference in counts.  You can do this by adding a numeric argument to your `palindromes` grammar term.

First I'll define an ordinary Prolog rule implementing "`B` is two more than `A`":

```
plus2(A,B) :- number(A), !, B is A+2.
plus2(A,B) :- number(B), !, A is B-2.
plus2(A,B) :- var(A), var(B), throw(error(instantiation_error,plus2/2)).
```

Then we'll say `palindromes(Diff)` means any palindrome on the given alphabet where the number of `b` letters minus the number of `a` letters is `Diff`.  For the base cases, you know `Diff` exactly:

```
palindromes(0) --> [].
palindromes(-1) --> [a].
palindromes(1) --> [b].
```

For the recursive grammar rules, we can use a code block in `{`braces`}` to check the `plus2` predicate:

```
palindromes(DiffOuter) --> [b], palindromes(DiffInner), [b],
    { plus2(DiffInner, DiffOuter) }.
palindromes(DiffOuter) --> [a], palindromes(DiffInner), [a],
    { plus2(DiffOuter, DiffInner) }.
```

To finish off, the top-level grammar rule is simply

```
please --> palindromes(1).
```